# Amazon SES received email address

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

When I receive an email, I would like to know, who was the specified recipient(I can't look in the to addresses/cc addresses/recipient addresses to look for my domain which is verified on SES, because I can see that there were multiple recipients with my domains). Therefore I am looking for kind of a header that would be able to show me, who is the recipient for that specific email(in case when I have two to addresses with my domains, i should receive two emails, for every address in SES).

I was looking for any header, that would specify that for me, but none of them worked, however I see that there is Received header in an email.

I know that every mail server on the "line" between the sender and receiver adds something to it and I cannot rely on their 100% truth, but I can rely on AWS SES. I decided to look for the value of this header:

```
Received: from SOME_SERVER (SOME_SERVER [SERVER_ID])
 by inbound-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com with SMTP id ID
 for MY_EMAIL_ADDRESS;
 Mon, 01 Feb 2021 14:51:39 +0000 (UTC)
```

As I see, there is my email address there, but I can't find any kind of documentation from AWS, that it will always be there. Do You have any information about it(some kind of link etc) or I shouldn't rely on that?

Are there any other solutions to see, who was the intended recipient for this email?

Comment: Adapting use of AWS SNS to fetch required details is an option for you? Such as [Contents of notifications for Amazon SES email receiving](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-notifications-contents.html). You can refer [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-notifications-examples.html).

Comment: only one field seemed to be the one that I am looking for - A list of recipients (specifically, the envelope RCPT TO addresses) that were matched by the active receipt rule. The addresses listed here may differ from those listed by the destination field in the mail object. - but RCPT TO header is the same as Received? So parsing should be enough?

Comment: That leads to another question - if someone sends mail to two recipients which are addeed to my receipt rule - does it mean, that I receive only one notification with two recipients?